# Using PigPIO library with Windows .NET application

Tags: c#, c, .net, raspberry-pi, pigpio

I'm just getting started in writing a C# application on Windows to interface with the GPIO of a Raspberry PI.  I've used the [PigPIO](https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio) library in the past with Python to make a remote connection with the RPI and manipulate the GPIO.  I'm trying to do the same thing with a C# forms application, but having trouble understanding how to integrate the raw .C code with the C# application.

I found the [PigPIO-dotnet](https://github.com/unosquare/pigpio-dotnet) wrapper written in C# that creates API's to interface to the .C Code.  It looks like it would work great if I was running my app under Linux but under Windows I'm getting an error at runtime for "Unable to load DLL file 'libpigpio.so'".  I'm assuming that because Windows uses .dll instead of .so libraries?

The Constants.cs file of PigPIO-dotnet starts out by referencing "libpigpio.so"

```
    internal static class Constants
    {
        internal const string PiGpioLibrary = "libpigpio.so";

        internal static readonly int[] HardwareClockPins0 = new[] { 4, 20, 32, 34 };

        internal static readonly int[] HardwareClockPins2 = new[] { 6, 43 };

        internal static readonly Dictionary<ResultCode, string> ResultCodeMessages = new Dictionary<ResultCode, string>()
```

I know basically nothing about C, so that's where I'm getting stuck.  I'm assuming that I need to recompile the C application as a .dll.  I've wore Google out looking at different tutorials on compiling C applications to .dll.  But nothing seems relevant to my question.

My question is...What is my next step if there is one?  I know that it is not possible to convert a .so to a .dll, so are there any steps I can take to create my own?

Comment: So you're trying to run your C# program on Windows but want to control the GPIO pins on the Raspi? I guess you used a communication protocol before and ran PigPIO on the raspi itself? Or how was the previous setup exactly?

Comment: Yes, I ran the PigPIO daemon on the RPI with no custom code.  I had downloaded the PigPIO Python library in Windows and wrote a small Python application that would connect to the daemon on the remote RPI and control the GPIO from my Python application.  The Python library is basically just a wrapper for the C code.

Comment: Then you now need a library that can talk to the deamon, not the hardware directly. Maybe you just need to reconfigure your tool (I do not know how PigPIO works). Or you switch to running the program directly on the Pi.